# Data Defined Override option is being ignored after modification in python function code

Tags: pyqgis, data-defined-override

In the function editor I made a Python function to control the font size of several layers (using **Data Defined Override** option).

But whenever I need to change something in the function's code and then I click on **Save and Load Function** button, the function stops being applied to the other layers (QGis starts to ignore the Data Defined Override option and starts to use the value in the Size field). It forces me to go to these other layers and open the expression editor just to click OK again. It is a time-consuming work because there are many layers using this function.

This problem is not restricted to the Size field of the labels. This happens in other situations, as in the option **Enable Symbol Layer**.

Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

QGis 3.28.5 (LTR)
Windows 11

Comment: Not the ideal solution but does closing and re-opening the project refresh the functions? It is likely much faster than doing each individually.

Comment: yeah, it works... but it sucks having to restart all the time. Mainly because I'm constantly testing small changes in the code.